# Tivoli Storage Manager Include Specific Directories

Tags: windows-server-2008, tivoli, tsm

In the Tivoli Storage Manager dsm.opt file, how do I tell it to include two specific directories, but exclude everything else.

For example, I want to backup the "E:\File Storage" and "F:\Documents" directories, but nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DOMAIN C: D: E: :F`

`EXCLUDE.DIR *:\...\[a-ln-oq-tv-z]*`

`EXCLUDE.DIR "*:\System Volume Information"`

`EXCLUDE.DIR "*:\...\Temporary Internet Files"`

`EXCLUDE.DIR "*:\Recycled"`

`EXCLUDE.DIR "*:\Recycler"`

`EXCLUDE.DIR "*:\$Recycle.Bin"`

`Exclude "*:\...\*"`

`Exclude "*:\*"`

`Include "E:\File Storage\*"`

`Include "F:\Documents\*"`